# Xcode, Command Line Tools, GCC, and HomeBrew

Tags: macos, xcode

I was following a Vuforia & Unity tutorial when I realized that (upon building for iOS) Xcode would not launch.

So, I issued the following commands at the Terminal to find out if I had Xcode installed:

```
$ xcode-select --version
xcode-select version 2343.

$ xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates.

$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

This all means that the full Xcode package is **not** installed on my Mac. Right?

If correct, do I necessarily have to download it from the App Store or can I also do it via HomeBrew?

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the following command line output:

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates.
```

it appears that you only have Xcode's command line tools installed. They are a requirement for running homebrew.

To build iOS apps you will have to download the full xcode package with the IDE and all the necessary tools. You can get Xcode from the AppStore: [Link](https://itunes.apple.com/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12)